# Absolute Path of Project's folder in Java

Tags: java, deployment, absolute-path

Lots of confusion in this topic. Several Questions have been asked. Things still seem unclear.
ClassLoader, Absolute File Paths etc etc

Suppose I have a project directory structure as,

```
MyProject--
            --dist        
            --lib
            --src
            --test
```

I have a resource say "txtfile.txt" in "lib/txt" directory. I want to access it in a system independent way. I need the absolute path of the project.
So I can code the path as abspath+"/lib/Dictionary/txtfile.txt"

Suppose I do this

```
 java.io.File file = new java.io.File("");   //Dummy file
    String  abspath=file.getAbsolutePath();
```

I get the current working directory which is not necessarily project root.

Suppose I execute the final 'prj.jar' from the 'dist' folder which also contains "lib/txt/txtfile.txt" directory structure and resource,It should work here too. I should absolute path of dist folder.

Hope the problem is clear.

Comment: Moreover I feel this approach is still restricted to "Unix" like directory structure platforms as appending  "/lib/Dictionary/txtfile.txt" on windows will mess it up due to forward and backslash differnces! :|

Comment: Actually, Java doesn't care about the slash directions, though you can only specify non-root drives explicitly since `/` points to the root of the current disk.

Comment: System.getProperty("file.separator") will return "\" for Windows environments and "/" for Unix (and Unix-like) ones.

Comment: @Catchwa, yep, that *is* the file separator, but Java will still recognize paths using forward slashes, try using them next time you need a path on Windows.

Comment: There are three variants of solution, depending on the situation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56327069/715269

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should really be using [getResource()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) or [getResourceAsStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) using your class loader for this sort of thing.  In particular, these methods use your ClassLoader to determine the search context for resources within your project.

Specify something like `getClass().getResource("lib/txtfile.txt")` in order to pick up the text file.

To clarify: instead of thinking about how to get the path of the resource you ought to be thinking about getting the resource -- in this case a file in a directory somewhere (possibly inside your JAR).  It's not necessary to know some absolute path in this case, only some URL to get at the file, and the ClassLoader will return this URL for you.  If you want to open a stream to the file you can do this directly without messing around with a URL using `getResourceAsStream`.

The resources you're trying to access through the ClassLoader need to be on the Class-Path (configured in the Manifest of your JAR file).  This is critical! The ClassLoader uses the Class-Path to find the resources, so if you don't provide enough context in the Class-Path it won't be able to find anything.  If you add `.` the ClassLoader should resolve anything inside or outside of the JAR depending on how you refer to the resource, though you can certainly be more specific.

Referring to the resource prefixed with a `.` will cause the ClassLoader to also look for files outside of the JAR, while not prefixing the resource path with a period will direct the ClassLoader to look only inside the JAR file.

That means if you have some file *inside* the JAR in a directory `lib` with name `foo.txt` and you want to get the resource then you'd run `getResource("lib/foo.txt");`

If the same resource were outside the JAR you'd run `getResource("./lib/foo.txt");`

Comment: Mark as I mentioned,I have already tried doing it will class loaders. Could you please post some snippet as to how to get about with it in my case?

Comment: @MArk I understood the fact that it has to be dealt by the class loader. but how? 
 java.net.URL url =getClass().getResource("lib/txtfile.txt");
returns a null URL for me!

Comment: @Mark The dist folder had a prj.jar + a "lib/txt/txtfile" resource. ( resource shipped outside jar )
I plan to tar the dist folder in the end to distribute it

Comment: @Myth17, in that case you need to add "." to the class path in the Manifest for the JAR and the call should be `getResource("lib/txt/txtfile")`

Comment: @MArk
I added this

java.net.URL url=getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("english.txt");      java.net.URL url2 =getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("common-misspells.txt");

where lib/Dictionary was in my classpath already.

sc.initialize(url.getPath(),url2.getPath());

where initialize was a library method I have to use.
This works when I compile from netbeans but the jar file in dist folder is still unable to find the dictionary files(although they are present there too).
Even The MANIFEST.MF has included :
Class-Path: lib/jaspellbin.jar lib/Dictionary

Comment: @Myth17: if lib/Dictionary is outside the JAR you still need to add `.` to the classpath, I suppose what you really want to add is `./lib/Dictionary`.

Comment: @Myth17, no problem, I'm going to clean up these comments into the actual answer and delete some of the extra discussion here -- I think it'll make for a more useable answer, suggest you do the same by moving some of the trial/error into your actual question.

Comment: Any chance you could update the links to getResource() and getResourceAsStream(). They're dead now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure the lib directory is in your classpath. You can do this by adding the command line parameter in your startup script:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -classpath .:lib com.example.MyMainClass
```

save this as MyProject/start.sh or any os dependent script.

Then you can access the textfile.txt (as rightly mentioned by Mark) as:

```
// if you want this as a File
URL res = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("text/textfile.txt");
File f = new File(res.getFile());

// As InputStream
InputStream in = getClass().getClassLoader()
        .getResourceAsStream("text/textfile.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

@Mark is correct.  That is by far the simplest and most robust approach.

However, if you really have to have a `File`, then your best bet is to try the following:

- turn the contents of the System property "java.class.path" into a list of pathnames,
- identify the JAR pathname in the list based on its filename,
- figure out what "../.." is relative to the JAR pathname to give you the "project" directory, and
- build your target path relative to the project directory.

Another alternative is to embed the project directory name in a wrapper script and set it as a system property using a -D option.  It is also possible to have a wrapper script figure out its own absolute pathname; e.g. using `whence`.