# System.getProperty("user.dir") does not work

Tags: java

I need to get relative path from my project to upload photos, however when I run `System.getProperty("user.dir");` in my test, it returns `/home/user/workspace/Myproject`,
but if I run it from my spring controller, it just returns `/home/user`.

Can anyone provide a insight that probably is happening?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `user.dir` property is the current working directory where you are running Java. You're starting java in `/home/user/workspace/Myproject` when you run your project but when Spring runs it, it's not guaranteed to be the same working directory. Are you looking for `user.home` (which should always be `/home/user`) instead?

Comment: No, I need to get the path project, regardless of computer the project is.

Comment: @DaniloM. In that case, you should take a look at `getResource()` intsead. It allows you to read files inside your projects directory. Here's a question about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209901/absolute-path-of-projects-folder-in-java

Comment: I solved my problem using `String path = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");`, which `request` is a `HttpServletRequest`. Thank you !