# How to get current directory in Spring?

Tags: java, string, spring, directory

I've got a little project in Spring. It's located (for example) in `C:/users/projects/blog`. How can I get this path?

Comment: A Java application has no knowledge of where it is. Only where it is started from, ie. which directory the `java` program is in (and even this is a hack and should not be used).

Comment: I've got a backup directory in my project. I want to add backups in there.

Comment: A backup of what? This is an [X Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Tell us what you want to do, we'll help you find a way to fix. Don't ask us what you want to do.

Comment: I know how to make backup. I just want to return project folder.

Comment: Return project folder from where? From a method with your application? I told you, that will only return the path to the `java` executable and I doubt that is also in your project's directory.

Comment: Refer to this regarding why user.dir doesnt work for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413952/system-getpropertyuser-dir-does-not-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java cannot determine the root of your project without projects meta data.
You can get the absolute path to your current class executing the code using the following :
YourClassName.class.getResource("").getPath()

Comment: Nope.`C:/Users/xxx/springsource/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.8.2.RELEASE/base-instance/wtpwebapps/blog/WEB-INF/classes/net/babobka/blog/controller/`

Comment: If this is only for backup purposes, I would have a java code at project root with the follwing content and use the path for backup:                        public class DirectoryPath{ 
 public static void main(String args[]){
  System.out.println("Path::::"+DirectoryPath.class.getResource("").getPath());  
 }
}

Comment: You get that because your java class is in package. You can try passing parameters to getResource("") and play with it.

Answer (score 13):

Maybe this what you looking for:

```
System.getProperty("user.dir")
```

This property returns user working directory for application.

Comment: It shows me `C:\Users\xxx\springsource\sts-3.2.0.RELEASE`, but I need `C:/users/projects/blog`

Comment: It's seems that you run application from spring tools suite. Is it web application or you can run it from command line?

Comment: It is web application. Yep.

Comment: So it this case your project files that located in `C:/users/projects/blog` are not associated to application when it launched on application container (tomcat for example).

Comment: And so? How to get path to project?

Comment: You can't. They not related when you launch application on container. If you want get access to same files just add it to classpath or use ProperyPlaceHolder or use Spring MVC resources (if you want manage js/css resources).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using a properties file. here is an example

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>file:${path}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
</bean>
```

while running your code you will need to pass in -Dpath=C:\users\projects\blog as an argument