# Difficult on accessing a video's directory

Tags: java

HELLO I made a video plays on a panel

and I get the video's url by this :

```
URL urlWaterIntake = new URL("file:///c:/tmp/water.avi");
```

BUT I moved the '**tmp**' folder inside the '**bin**' folder of eclipse IDE , and now
i access by this :

```
URL urlWaterIntake = new URL("file:///tmp/water.avi");
```

AND ERRORR !!! voila !! what a life ...  , some solutions ??

btw i tried this one too :

```
File myFile = new File("tmp/water.avi");
URL urlWaterIntake = new URL(myFile.toURI().toURL());
```

BUT NOTHING WORKS.....

Comment: Are you using it inside Applet or inside JSP or anything else?

Comment: possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3209987/2777098

Comment: No, its inside JFrame

Comment: @ IsabelHM , yeaaaaaaaahhhhhhhhhhhhhhh !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! that works .... thanks browwwwww.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `System#getProperty()` to get the below directories if you want to use **absolute path** under Windows system.

```
String userHome = System.getProperty("user.home");     
String tempDir  = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
```

---

Read from **same package** where the class is present

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("water.avi");
```

OR

Read from **tmp** folder parallel to **src** in your project

```
File file = new File("tmp/water.avi");
URL urlWaterIntake = file.toURI().toURL();
```

Comment: thankssss ... this "URL url = this.getClass().getResource("water.avi");" works like a heroo...